# boost::integer_mask gcc compiler error

Tags: c++, gcc, boost

I'm unable to compile the following code (using boost 1.61 ).

```
#include <boost/integer/integer_mask.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    uint a =  boost::low_bits_mask_t<1>::sig_bits;
    std::cout << "bitmask " << a << std::endl;
}
```

On clang it compiles fine.
With g++ (version 6.2.1) I get

```
 file included from /usr/include/boost/config.hpp:61:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/integer_fwd.hpp:15,
                 from /usr/include/boost/integer/integer_mask.hpp:13,
                 from boostbug.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/integer/integer_mask.hpp: In instantiation of ‘const least boost::low_bits_mask_t<1ul>::sig_bits’:
boostbug.cpp:7:42:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/integer/integer_mask.hpp:66:5: error: left operand of shift expression ‘(-1 << 1ul)’ is negative [-fpermissive]
     BOOST_STATIC_CONSTANT( least, sig_bits = (~( ~(least( 0u )) << Bits )) );
     ^
```

What am I doing wrong?
Is this a gcc or a boost bug?

Answer (score 3):

Let's analyze the `~(least( 0u )) << Bits` expression.  Why does this become -1?  First, the `least` type will be the smallest type that can hold the number of bits you want (1).  This will be `unsigned char`, so the expression now looks like `~(unsigned char( 0u )) << Bits`.  The `~` operator will perform integral promotions.  This results in the `unsigned char` being promoted to `int` (signed), because that type is the first in the list of types that an unsigned char can be promoted to and it will hold all the possible values.  The ones' complement of 0, when interpreted as a signed integer in a system that uses a twos complement is -1.  The shift left of a negative integer is undefined behavior, which is why you get the error you see.

`sig_bits_fast` has this same problem, so it does not provide a solution.

This is a boost bug, since the boost header code relies on undefined behavior (left shift of a signed quantity).

Comment: Actually it still doesnt compile with `sig_bits_fast`, throwing the same error.

Comment: @Dreamcooled I speculated, based on looking at the header.  I've updated my answer to remove that incorrect guess.

Comment: I think your answer correctly describes the root of the problem: The integer promotions for n < 16.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that you do anything wrong. It is clearly compiler bug.
I compiled your code with online http://cpp.sh/ compiler.

I could also check it with VS2015 and boost 1.58.

```
#include <boost/integer/integer_mask.hpp>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  uint a0 =  boost::low_bits_mask_t<0>::sig_bits;
  std::cout << "bitmask <0> = " << a0 << std::endl;   
  uint a =  boost::low_bits_mask_t<1>::sig_bits;
  std::cout << "bitmask <1> = " << a << std::endl;    
  uint b =  boost::low_bits_mask_t<2>::sig_bits;    
  std::cout << "bitmask <2> = " << b << std::endl;   
  uint c =  boost::low_bits_mask_t<3>::sig_bits;    
  std::cout << "bitmask <3> = " << c << std::endl;   
  uint d =  boost::low_bits_mask_t<4>::sig_bits;    
  std::cout << "bitmask <4> = " << d << std::endl;
}
```

Result:

```
bitmask <0> = 0
bitmask <1> = 1
bitmask <2> = 3
bitmask <3> = 7
bitmask <4> = 15
```

Comment: On second thought: I don't think it's a compiler bug, and the other answer correctly identifies the root of the problem: Integer promotions.